# Setting system recording level in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, naudio, audio, winmm

Clicking the speaker icon in the taskbar, then recording devices, then microphone, then level, I can see the recording level and change it manually if necessary.

I would like to change, set or get this number programmically in vs 2010 vb.net

I have tried using Mark Heath's NAudio to get or set this number, but his code is not in vb, and I can't seem to get it converted to make it work.

Can anyone help me just find a simple way to set and get this value?

I have been all over the internet for weeks, so I probably read everything a search engine can provide.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Libraries are meant to be included and used, not converted. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have included NAudio and have used many of its functions, however, I don't believe that monitoring the microphone level is one of them.  If it is, please show me the code, please...

Answer (score 0):

Use `mixerGetControlDetails / mixerSetControlDetails` API calls to get and set any volume level, whether it is input level or output level.

I remember seeing a nice example on how to make this work ( see this [article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/sound/article.php/c10931/Windows-Mixer-Control-in-C.htm) ), the idea being to talk directly to the "Windows Mixer Control" via these API calls.

Hope this helps.